# Top branches (with maximum predictive power) of a decision tree in R

Tags: r, random-forest, decision-tree, modeling

I want to build a decision tree on my data of 200+ variables to classify it into 2-3 groups. But before I build it, I wanted to know if there is a way to get all branches in a data frame/table/excel or any other type of object? Basically I want to get all the top branches/combinations of variables which have the maximum predictive/classification power. Is there a way to get it in R? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: 1. You cannot get the splits before building the model, 2. This may not be what you want, the top splits are not necessarily the best ones.

Comment: @user2974951 Yes obviously. Lets say I've built the model/decision tree. What I know is that I will be able to get variables and corresponding importance/information value etc. But can I know like (as an exmple) that these combinations like "var1 = a and var2 = b and var3 = a ......." is able to identify 90% of group1 and so on.?

Comment: That will be very hard with a random forest, if you want such rules you should use a decision tree. Random forests are meant as black box, you don't really interpret them.

Comment: I thought so. Can you please recommend what package/function would be best for a decision tree?

Comment: `rpart` is probably the most used implementation of CART.